# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot bind argument at index 0 because the index is out of range. The statement has 4 parameters

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Android SQLLite gives me the following error:

```
 SQLiteStatement tgStatement = dbo.compileStatement("INSERT OR REPLACE INTO Game_Team" +
                "(teamId, gameId, pos, score) VALUES (?,?,?,?) ");
```

Thats why I try to do:

```
tgStatement.bindLong(0, 1);
```

I get an error

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot bind argument at index 0 because the index is out of range.`

The statement has 4 parameters.

So, my question is, if there are 4 parameters, why is it complaining about argument at index 0? how is that out of range?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The parameters are 1-indexed. The index needs to run from 1 to 4, so 0 is out of range.

Comment: Oh wow. just when I didn't expect. I spent countless hours trying to figure this out. Searching left and right, and then I finally broke... thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

This trick might come handy to some.

```
SQLiteStatement tgStatement = dbo.compileStatement("INSERT OR REPLACE INTO Game_Team" +
                "(teamId, gameId, pos, score) VALUES (?,?,?,?) ");
    int i = 1;
    tgStatement.bindLong(i++, teamId);
    tgStatement.bindLong(i++, gameId);
    tgStatement.bindString(i++, pos);
    tgStatement.bindLong(i++, score);
```

Above trick is useful when you have more parameters, it avoid missing on indices as well as numbering them. i variable handles the indice.

Answer (score 1):

Indices start at 1. So it's setLong(1,1)